# Remove newline *before* \section

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have searched a lot to find an answer to this question, but I could only find how to remove a newline *after* \section (or \chapter).

How can one remove the newline *before* \section, as defined by book class?

Basically, looking at the MWE below, I am looking to a way to have:

```
Text before. Section heading
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}        
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont}{\thesection.}{0pt}{}

\titlespacing{\section}
   {0pt}% left
   {0pt}% before
   {0pt}% after

\begin{document}
Text before. \section*{Section heading} Text after
\end{document}
```

I can't find any option with titlesec and I would not want to enter the esoteric intricacies of TeX class redefinitions.

I would be grateful for any hint or pointer on how to deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}        
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar\mystarsec\mynostarsec}
\makeatother

\newcommand\mystarsec[1]{%
\ifhmode\unskip\fi\quad\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand\mynostarsec[1]{%
\ifhmode\unskip\fi\refsetepcounter{section}\quad\textbf{\thesection. #1}}

\begin{document}
Text before. \section*{Section heading} Text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Would this preserve all the benefits given by the standard book class for that command (like TOC, etc)?

Comment: @gsl no, as written it doesn't have the `[short for toc]` option nor does it write to the TOC (or the page head) it could (I may update later if you want that) but in that case it would be a (bit) easier if instead of redefining `\section` you redefined the lower level `\@startsection` but in that case `\subsection`, `\paragraph` etc would also be redefined to be inline, would that be OK?

Comment: Yes, that would be better (to redefine `\@startsection`), as it seems it would be easier later on to add space where necessary than to remove. Thank you so much.