# No newline before section, preserve header info

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, line-breaking

I am trying to achieve the same as this post:
[Remove newline *before* \section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/remove-newline-before-section)
But the problem is that with the suggested solution the section information cannot be used in the header. Is there any way that I can remove the newline before a subsection and at the same time keep the section information for the header? I need a running header with the first and last section and subsection information.

Basically I'm trying to achieve a combination of this:
[No newline before section, preserve header info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365149/no-newline-before-section-preserve-header-info#)

And this:
[Chapters and verses of current page in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26274/chapters-and-verses-of-current-page-in-header)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes how you use your header?

Comment: This sounds like a very odd requirement. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just edited the question with more details.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Latex so I don't have a MWE. Just trying to get ideas from the links I've added.

Comment: I did understand what you want, but *why* do you want it? A section  title in the middle of running text is very unusual and I suspect that you actually want something different.

Comment: Basically what I want is the verse information in the header. (first and last verse, chapter of the current page). Maybe using subsections is not the best approach, but I don't how else to get the verse info sent to the Header.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this, the key is to use `\markright` (or `\markboth` or one of the other mark commands) to leave a mark on the page, the page heading can then pick up the first and last mark on the page and use accordingly.  In the standard classes `\section` uses `\markright` (with chapter level marks using the left mark) so I did the same here, defining a simple `\section` that uses a counter and leaves a mark but no optional handling or star form, and very little heading formatting

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[paperheight=8cm,paperwidth=7cm, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand\section[1]{%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\textsection\thesection\markright{#1}~\textit{#1} %
}

\begin{document}

%\chapter{zzz} omit this as page heading is open on chapter start pages by default
\refstepcounter{chapter}

\section{Start} something about the beginning \section{This} and a bit more
\section{That} A longer section about something that has more than one paragraph.

It seems a bit odd to have a paragraph more distinguished than a section heading, so perhaps that is not needed. \section{Then} and sections will always be inline.

\section{Later} or at the start of a paragraph.

\section{Second Start} something about the beginning \section{Second This} and a bit more
\section{Second That} A longer section about something that has more than one paragraph.

It seems a bit odd to have a paragraph more distinguished than a section heading, so perhaps that is not needed. \section{Second Then} and sections will always be inline.

\section{Second Later} or at the start of a paragraph.

\section{Third} Is surprisingly different to the first two.
\end{document}
```